# Constructing a url with query strings

Tags: python, url

How do I properly construct urls with query strings?

For example, from a website, I scrape the value `www.abc.com/SomethingHere?x=1&y=2` however, the value I get uplon scraping is `www.abc.com/SomethingHere?x=1&amp;y=2` sometimes there's wierd `%xx` at the end I don't understand. Requests made with these modified strings fail (but are ok if I manually remove the amp and percentage wierdness). It also makes me afraid of adding more query parameters with just `www.abc.com/SomethingHere?x=1&amp;y=2&z=3`

How do I make sure I get the proper urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in two steps:

```
import urllib

# first parse the url
>>> parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse('www.abc.com/SomethingHere?x=1&amp;y=2')
>>> parsed
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='www.abc.com/SomethingHere', params='', query='x=1&amp;y=2', fragment='')

# the parse the query string component (into a dictionary)
>>> q = parsed.query
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs(q)
{'y': ['2'], 'x': ['1']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at `urlparse` in python ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)). Calling `urlparse` on your query, we get something like:

```
urlparse('www.abc.com/SomethingHere?x=1&amp;y=2&z=3')
Output: ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='www.abc.com/SomethingHere', params='', query='x=1&amp;y=2&z=3%%xx', fragment='')
```

For modifying query params you can further use `urljoin`, as follows:

```
urljoin('www.abc.com/SomethingHere?x=1&amp;y=2&z=3%%xx', '?x=2')
Output: 'www.abc.com/SomethingHere?x=2'
```

Comment: Thank you. How to get rid of `amp;` and other idiosyncracies sytematically (i.e, other than `str.replace`)